# Switching BottomNavigationView tabs causes crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationView` with several tabs. Each tab contains a Fragment. When selecting a fragment that is calling a Json from the web and quickly switching to another tab, the app crashes.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher

Here is my code:

```
fun fetchJson(theRecycler: RecyclerView) {
    val request = Request.Builder().url("someUrl").build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val myFeed = gson.fromJson(body, WebFragment::class.java)

            activity!!.runOnUiThread{
                theRecycler.adapter = WebAdapter(myFeed.items)
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println("Failed to execute request")
        }
    })
}
```

The error seems to be happening at this line:

```
            activity!!.runOnUiThread{
                theRecycler.adapter = WebAdapter(myFeed.items)
            }
```

I think I need to stop this process `onStop()` but I'm not sure how I would proceed to do this.

> 2019-01-24 22:25:49.390 22261-22510/com.app E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
>       Process: com.app, PID: 22261
>       kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>           at com.app.UI.Navigation.HomeFeed.NewsFeed$fetchJson$1.onResponse(HomeFeed.kt:45)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
>           at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: Well you code is unsafe. At least use `activity?.runOnUiThread` or rework your code to split responsabilities.